# Periodic multi-layer scattering of neutrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, particle-physics, large-hadron-collider, optical-materials

I am trying to understand the reflectivity plot on slide 26 of [Neutron optics,Soldner lecture](http://www.phys.utk.edu/neutron-summer-school/lectures/soldner-01.pdf).

1.Is the peak from $\theta$=0.0 to 0.4 due to total external reflection from the first upper surface?.

2.There is another peak at $\theta$=1.0. Is it because of Bragg's interference?(As given in slide 23 of [Stewart's lectures](http://www.oxfordneutronschool.org/2011/lectures/osns_stewart_polarised_2011.pdf).

3.Why are there alternative peaks between $\theta$=0.4 and 1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the answers:

1. Yes.
2. Yes... But is it better called as Darwin's plateau.
3. Those are fine structure arising from multiple wave interference (and are not seen experimentally) (see page [16](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.0849.pdf) of Analysis and design of multilayer structures
   for neutron monochromators and supermirrors ,S. Masalovich )